# SQL Server 2008 group selection based results

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains 6 columns and each column has an int value between 1 to 16 there are rows having different combinations

I have an combination 12345?

I want a rows on basis of this sixth number

Table

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
-----------------------------------------    
  1     2      3      4      5      6
  1     9      3      4      5      7
  1     7      5      2      1      3
```

Output :

- if sixth number is 6 there is match of 6/6
- if number is 7 the match is 5/6
- if the number is 3 the match is 2/6 ... so on

This SQL Server and output should be rows like sixth

Colname

results should be like this

```
Selection    6/6     5/6     4/6    3/6   2/6   1/6
     1        0       0        1     1      5   200
     2        1       5      200     3    440   560
     .
     .
     .
     .
    14       10       2      200    40     60   500
```

Comment: You're going to have to tell us more.  What are the rules for selection or arrangement of the table in your example to get the output?  You say "... and so on" but it isn't at all clear what the rules are.

Comment: Also, what have you tried to do?  Do you have a query or algorithm that gets you part of the way?

Comment: for example a dice dice is thrown 5 times and result is according to that now its a estimation of sixth time if on sixth time the dice thown the out put be expected on that number
if result of sith dice is 1 then and if sixth dice results 2 and rows will selected

Comment: I have to agree with [Ann L.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/490374/ann-l), I cannot understand your description of the meaning of your input data and the logic which should be used to arrive at the desired result. Please explain more clearly (perhaps with more examples to help us), plus detail what you have already tried and what went wrong and someone may be able to give you some help with this.

Comment: welll i have have a table contains six columns each column have a one number from 0 to 14 as shown below 

col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
-----------------------------------------    
  1     2      3      4      5      6
  1     9      3      4      5      7
  1     7      5      2      1      3

now i have to work on this table  i have a dice having 6 out comes 

1 
2
3
4
5
 ?
the sixth value is not known 
i have to write a query which will give  me estimation that if the sixth value is 1 then the no of matches to first table is either 6/6 or 5/6 or 4/6 or